# Cumulative weighted average in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to implement a cumulative weighted average function that takes as argument the 
list

```
[[1000, 3.1], [500, 1.2], [800, 7.1], [1300, 8.88]]
```

and returns (rounded to 2 decimal places here)

```
[3.1, 2.47, 4.08, 5.81]
```

For, example: 2.47 = (1000 * 3.1 + 500 * 1.2) / 1500.

I have currently solved this using the following piece of code:

```
def cumulative_weighted_average(list)
  cs = 0
  qu = 0
  res = list.inject([0]) do |s, el|
    cs += el[0] * el[1]
    qu += el[0]
    s + [cs.to_f / qu]
  end
  res.shift
  res
end
```

Is there a shorter (more compact) way of doing this?

**Edit:**
Thanks for the answers below! The list will on average contain about 1000 entries, so not sure about the speed requirement. Since I need to be able to essentially track two values within the block, is there some extension of inject that allows you to write

```
list.inject([0,0]){ |s1, s2, el| ...}
```

where s1 and s2 are initialized to 0?

Comment: Could you be clearer about rounding? If you don't actually want it, it may be better that your example output is not rounded.

Comment: @NeilSlater I think it is clear enough that the OP does not particularly want rounding. Note the question says "rounded to 2 decimal places **here**".

Comment: You don't need "some extension of `inject`". The accumulator can be any arbitrary object, so of course it can also be an `Array`. `list.inject([0,0]){ |(s1, s2), el| ...}` works just fine with the standard `inject`, no need for any sort of extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
def cumulative_weighted_average list
  cs, qu = 0.0, 0.0
  list
  .map{|x, w| [cs += x * w, qu += x]}
  .map{|cs, qu| cs / qu}
end

cumulative_weighted_average([[1000, 3.1], [500, 1.2], [800, 7.1], [1300, 8.88]])
# => [3.1, 2.466666666666667, 4.078260869565217, 5.812222222222222]
```

---

For the additional question, things like this are possible:

```
list.inject([0,0]){|(s1, s2), el| ...}
```

Comment: use also `round`;then output would match with OP's one.

Comment: @Priti: I don't think the OP is interested in rounding in the algorithm, the example output was rounded for brevity in the question.

Comment: @NeilSlater I also withdrawn `round` from mine one. :) may be I concentrated to the output not his sentences... :) but thanks to point me there...

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a shorted (more compact) way of doing this?

I can try for you..

```
arr = [[1000, 3.1], [500, 1.2], [800, 7.1], [1300, 8.88]]
arr2 = (1..arr.size).map do |i| 
  b = arr.take(i)
  b.reduce(0){|sum,a| sum + a.reduce(:*)}/b.reduce(0){|sum,k| sum + k[0]}
end
arr2
# => [3.1, 2.466666666666667, 4.078260869565217, 5.812222222222222]
```

Comment: The main problem I would have with this is it is O(n**2) on size of input array, as it recalculates the sums for each position in the cumulative array

Comment: @NeilSlater can you see now ?

Comment: It's still O(n**2). You split the array up into sub arrays of each possible length and operate of each of those arrays. This is "triangular" numbers, which means for some of the items you do `(n)(n+1)/2` calculations where `n` would do. This would really start to tell if the original array was e.g. 100 items.

Comment: OK.. so which I part,you would suggest me to improve.

Comment: The OP's strategy of keeping count-so-far and sum-so-far, and incrementing them for each element is essentially correct. Any re-structuring of the original code should preserve that in some way. I'd suggest attempt from scratch, but you don't have to - your answer *works*, it is just weaker at handling longer lists. Perhaps the OP doesn't need long lists.

Comment: @NeilSlater The OP's code is O(n^2) as well by the way (because of `Array#+` being O(n)).

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the "outer" temporary variables, and make things look a little cleaner, and idiomatic Ruby, if you allow for a two-stage calculation (which is not necessarily slower, same amount of maths is involved):

```
def cumulative_weighted_average list
  cumulative_totals = list.inject( [] ) do |cumulative,item|
    tot_count, tot_sum = cumulative.last || [0, 0.0]
    next_count, next_value = item
    cumulative << [ tot_count + next_count,  tot_sum + next_count * next_value ]
  end
  cumulative_totals.map { |count,sum| sum/count }
end

p cumulative_weighted_average( 
    [[1000, 3.1], [500, 1.2], [800, 7.1], [1300, 8.88]] )

=> [3.1, 2.46666666666667, 4.07826086956522, 5.81222222222222]
```